# WPF - Mostrar Columnas de un DataGrid dependiendo el Valor que le asigne a un Control como Slider o TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

### Mostrar Columnas de un DataGrid dependiendo la cantidad que le Asigne mediante otros Controles

*Muy Buenas Noches, aunque para mí hoy ha sido un día no tan bueno porque que me he pasado todo el día intentado lograr este objetivo y no pude.*
**El objetivo consiste en ingresar cualquier valor**, **Y dependiendo de ESE valor mostrarme tal cantidad de Columnas.**

---

- Yo quisiera hacerlo de esta Manera: Mediante un Slider, con un Máximo de 10. Entonces, mientras vaya moviendo el pulgar(thumb) me muestra esa cantidad correspondiente (en entero) mediante un TextBox. Entonces, si la cantidad es 5, Que el DataGrid me Muestre o Crée esa Cantidad de Columnas.

---

**XAML**

```
<Grid Background="#FFFB9C4C">
    <Slider x:Name="valores" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Height="41" Margin="0,373,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208"
            TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            Maximum="5" Minimum="0" ValueChanged="valores_ValueChanged" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="321" Margin="37,19,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="717" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="1" Header="PRUEBA 1"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="2" Header="PRUEBA 2"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="3" Header="PRUEBA 3"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox x:Name="numero" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42"
             Margin="510,362,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="56" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="18"/></Grid>
```

**CS**

```
private void valores_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        int V_valor = (int)valores.Value;
        numero.Text = V_valor.ToString();

    }
```

Desde ya que es evidente que soy MUY NOVATO en esto, pero me gustaría que me ayuden por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas:

```
private void valores_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    datagrid.Columns.Clear(); //Borramos todo
    int cantidad =Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValue);
    for(int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
    {
        datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Prueba " + (i + 1) });
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, para que funcione bien al inicio el valor del slider debe tener las mismas cantidades de columnas, entonces como el slider comienza en cero debes sacar las columnas que tienen en el XAML:

```
<Slider x:Name="valores" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Height="41" Margin="0,373,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208"
    TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
    Maximum="5" Minimum="0" ValueChanged="valores_ValueChanged"/>
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="321" Margin="37,19,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="717" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Wow! Aún no lo pruebo pero MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS Buen Hombre!!!